# passing different type variables to the view from controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

i want to pass two variables called as **repcounter** and **suppliers** to the view to do two different task.
here is my function in controller,

```
 public function admin()
    {

        $suppliers = SupplierData::all();
       $repcounter= SalesRep::count();


        return view('dashboard', compact('suppliers'));
    }
```

this is how i send suppliers data. it worked fine. but i don't have an idea to send repcounter and suppliers at once.. each time i try i gave error undefined variable.
so how to send this two varibles to the dashboard.blade.php view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function admin()
    {

        $suppliers = SupplierData::all();
       $repcounter= SalesRep::count();


        return view('dashboard', compact('suppliers','repcounter'));
    }
```

Comment: @Pasindu Senarath: If my answer is work for you then please accept my answer

Comment: thanks it worked. can i use this for more variables? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @PasinduSenarath: Yes you add more variables same as `repcounter`

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
return view('dashboard', compact('suppliers'));
```

With the following code:

```
return view('dashboard', compact('suppliers,'repcounter'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple variables to the view by nesting the data you want in an array. See below code.

```
public function admin()
    {

        //create an empty array
        $response = array();

        //nest your data insde the array instead of creating variables
        $response['suppliers'] = SupplierData::all();
        $response['repcounter'] = SalesRep::count();


        return view('dashboard', compact('response'));
    }
```

Inside your View, you can access them as below

```
$response['suppliers']
$response['repcounter']
```